# solr LowerCaseFilterFactory should not filter number

Tags: java, solr

I'm using a query schema which need to let `abc` match `Abc` and `400` match `400` (user name match).

But I found when I use `LowerCaseFilterFactory`, It not return any result when I query `400`.
I digg into the source code, and found `LowerCaseTokenizerFactory` use `LowerCaseTokenizer` which extends `LetterTokenizer`, and it filter all the numbers.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that `LowerCaseTokenizer` will remove all non-letters.  It would very useful (as far as providing a meaningful answer) to see your schema, as I don't believe just using the lowercase filter factory should generate a `Tokenizer` of any kind.

At any rate, though, there are plenty of other options for tokenizers.  Both [`Standard`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory) or [`Classic`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory) might suit your needs better.

Something along the line of:

```
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Might do well for you.